# Retrieving JSON Values

Tags: php, json

I am working with a php payment api https://simplepay4u.com/developer.php
I have followed every step successfully but can't seem to get return values to generate a receipt after payment. I am stock not understanding the what the unotify page should be doing.

Here is my form which is posting properly:

```
$action         = $_POST["action"];
$pid            = $_POST["pid"];
$buyer          = $_POST["buyer"];
$total          = $_POST["total"];
$comments       = $_POST["comments"];
$referer        = $_POST["referer"];
$customid       = $_POST["customid"];
$transaction_id = $_POST["customid"];
$val            = @json_encode($_POST);
// For Loging $val can be used
if ($referer == "https://simplepay4u.com"
    || $referer == "https://www.simplepay4u.com"
    || "http://sandbox.simplepay4u.com/process.php") //1st level checking
{
    if (!empty($transaction_id)) //2nd level checking
    {
        /*** Server side verification. Your server is communicating with Simplepay Server Internally**/
        //$simplepay_url="https://simplepay4u.com/processverify.php"; // Live URL
        $simplepay_url   = "http://sandbox.simplepay4u.com/processverify.php";
        $curldata["cmd"] = "_notify-validate";
        foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'view' && $key != 'layout') {
                $value          = urlencode($value);
                $curldata[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        $handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $simplepay_url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curldata);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);
        $result = curl_exec($handle);
        curl_close($handle);
        var_dump(json_decode($result));

        enter code here
        if ('VERIFIED' == $result) {
            //  IMPLEMENTATION CODE & aPPLICATION lOGIC WILL GO HER TO UPDATE THE ACCOUNT
        }
    }
}
```

I have set my ureturn page to carry the above script and tried `var_dump(json_decode($result))`, `print_r($result)` and `echo $result;` Just to see something but I get the result.

Can someone please tell me what to do to get my return values after posting my already working form?

Comment: Just one note before continue reading your code, you should never accept referrals from Non-SSL host, since it's a payment gateway they will neve use non-secured domain for the payment process

Comment: show us a snippet of the print_r. i don't think you can just do a comparison with the $result object directly. you'll probably have to treat it like an object. see examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: You know you're missing `$referer ==` on your last `||` condition?

Comment: Is `enter code here` something you've added or is it actually in the script ? The PHP interpreter will give an error because of it.